# Move to other end of paragraph in vim (not a visual block)

Tags: vim

If I have a paragraph selected in visual mode (eg, `vap`), I can swap the cursor between the ends by using Shift-O. Is there a way to do this in normal mode?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use { and } to go to the start or the end of a paragraph in normal mode.

From `:help object-motions`

```
5. Text object motions                                  *object-motions*

                                                        *(*
(                       [count] sentences backward.  |exclusive| motion.

                                                        *)*
)                       [count] sentences forward.  |exclusive| motion.

                                                        *{*
{                       [count] paragraphs backward.  |exclusive| motion.

                                                        *}*
}                       [count] paragraphs forward.  |exclusive| motion.
```

Comment: Yes, but how do toggle/swap ends. In other words, what one key will swap ends regardless of which end you are on?

Comment: @TylerDurden There is no swap key. Just use `{}`.